# Setting private Git server with SSH disabled

Tags: git, ssh, redhat

I need to setup a private Git server through Nginx on RHEL 7 machine where SSH connection is not permitted.

The problem is when initializing the bare repository, which needs to execute the command `git --bare init`.

Is it possible to make a bare repository without SSH connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can not do a remote SSH connection to the RHEL machine? I assume you can not use telnet or other means of issuing bash commands.

If you can download files, you can perhaps try to do the `git --bare init` command in another computer, then compress this file, send it to the RHEL machine, and uncompress it. Is that possible for you? If not, please tell us what can you do with the remote machine.